# Image not assigned ID in R

Tags: android, r.java-file

I am trying to set an image to change while focused.

Error I am getting-"practiceon cannot be resolved or is not a field"

```
     ImageView practicemode =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.practiceoff);
    practicemode.setFocusable(true);
    if (practicemode.isFocused() == true) {practice.setImageResource(R.id.practiceon);}
```

The image is in the same folder as practiceoff. Nothing is different- except after reading my R.java I see that practiceon has no int assigned to it under id (but it is mentioned in drawable. What would be a fix to this?

*I have cleaned and restarted several times.

Comment: Have you modified the auto generated files at all? Also, are there *any* errors in your application? That happened to me once and it was because of an error with one of my XML files. If there's an error in one of your XML files, then the whole R.java won't compile correctly.

Comment: No there were no errors and i don't touch the auto gen files.
Although the ID still hasn't been assigned I used r.drawable instead of r.id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All image files should be in one of the drawable folders, and can be accessed through R drawable.*

Comment: Deetadee. Stupid am i. practice.setImageResource(R.drawable.practiceon)
Thanks.